# VBA comparing code

Tags: vba, excel

My VBA code compare 2 columns in the same sheet he compares columns A and B and put the results in columns D and E .

i have in column A "communities R1" different than thoes in columns B 
"communities R2"  in column D i have data that exist in column A but not in column B  and in column E i have data that exist in column B but not in column A .
   it work just fin but there is one problem is that  when i execut the code the headers of column A and B desepers. can you please help me find a solution ?

this is the code:

```
Sub two_cols()

Dim d1 As Object, d2 As Object, d3 As Object, e
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("D2:E30000").Clear



Set d1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set d2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set d3 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Cells(1) = Range("A2")
Cells(2) = Range("B2")
For Each e In Cells(1).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row).Value
    d1(e) = True
    d2(e) = True
Next e

For Each e In Cells(2).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(3).Row).Value
    If (d2(e)) * (d1.exists(e)) Then d1.Remove e
    If Not d2(e) Then d3(e) = True
Next e

On Error Resume Next
Range("D2").Resize(d1.Count) = Application.Transpose(d1.keys)
Range("E2").Resize(d3.Count) = Application.Transpose(d3.keys)
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

and this is the file : http://www.cjoint.com/c/FCFoqR7niZv

Comment: did you actually step through the code line-by-line and see where the A and B headers disappear? That will give you a good idea how to fix it, I think.

Comment: well i start the comparaison in A2 but even tho it disappears , i dont know what is the problem  in the code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a result of :
Cells(1) = Range("A2")
Cells(2) = Range("B2")

These are setting your Header cells to the value of A2 and B2
if you comment these out you will not lose your header row but you will find you are comparing your header row. I suggest the following version of your script:

```
Sub two_cols()

Dim d1 As Object, d2 As Object, d3 As Object, e
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("D2:E30000").Clear



Set d1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set d2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set d3 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
'Cells(1) = Range("A2")
'Cells(2) = Range("B2")
Dim header1 As Boolean
Dim header2 As Boolean
header1 = True
header2 = True

For Each e In Cells(1).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row).Value
    If header1 = False Then
        d1(e) = True
        d2(e) = True
    Else
        header1 = False
       End If
Next e

For Each e In Cells(2).Resize(Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(3).Row).Value
    If header2 = False Then
        If (d2(e)) * (d1.exists(e)) Then d1.Remove e
        If Not d2(e) Then d3(e) = True
    Else
        header2 = False
    End If
Next e

On Error Resume Next
Range("D2").Resize(d1.Count) = Application.Transpose(d1.keys)
Range("E2").Resize(d3.Count) = Application.Transpose(d3.keys)
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanx a lot it works perfectly , i am new to VBA so i am just starting to get experience , thanx again